# how to pass datalist values from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I have written a jsp file and servlet .In jsp I have used data list inside a form .And I want to pass that user input to the servlet.I have posted the code below.

**jsp code**

```
 <form  action="NewServlet1" method="Post" >
<center>
        <input type="text" name="website" list="website" placeholder="Enter your website">
        <datalist id="website">
        <option value="https://www.google.lk/">GOOGLE</option>
        <option value="https://www.yahoo.com/">YAHOO</option>
        <option value="https://www.hackerrank.com/">HACKER RANK</option>

        </datalist><br><br><br>

    </center></form>

     <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="1000" height="1000" ></canvas>
    </div>
<center> <div>
       <button id="button1"  name="button1" onclick="submit()" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    </div></center>
    <script>
        function Test(today, time) {
            var ctx = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart")

            , {

                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: today,
                    datasets: [{
                            data: time,
                            label: "Web Service 1",
                            borderColor: "red",
                            fill: false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options:
                        {
                            scales: {xAxes: [{display: true, scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'date and time'}}], yAxes: [{display: true, ticks: {beginAtZero: true, steps: 100, stepValue: 50, max: 6000}}]},

                            hover: {intersect: false },
                            title: {display: true, text: 'response time of selected website'},
                              tooltips: { mode: 'nearest'}

                        }
            });
}
function submit()
{

    $.post("NewServlet1",
            {

            },
            function (data)
            {

                Test(data.today, data.time);
            });
}
```

**servlet code**

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

       response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

       String website = (String)request.getParameter("website");
```

But this is not working.Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: what you get as from `request.getParameter("website")` after submiting ??

Comment: I am calculating the response time of the selected website and drawing graph by using that data and when I took this website variable and drew the it is showing wrong graph . But if I used   ' String website = "https://www.google.lk/";'  it is showing real graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to submit the form to the servlet which path is mapped to `NewServlet1`

```
<form  action="NewServlet1" method="Get" >
    <center>
            <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Enter your website">
            <datalist id="website">
            <option value="https://www.google.lk/">GOOGLE</option>
            <option value="https://www.yahoo.com/">YAHOO</option>
            <option value="https://www.hackerrank.com/">HACKER RANK</option>

            </datalist>
    </center>
        <%
        String website= request.getParameter("website"); // it is not needed
        request.setAttribute("website",website);         // it is not needed
        %>
    <input type="submit"/> <!--need to add submit button to submit it to the servlet-->
</form>
```

Now your servlet code is fine which is:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String website = (String)request.getParameter("website");
}
```

Note : Need to write some value in `website` text box

Or if you want to get `attribute` which previously stored in `request` object then use `RequestDispatcher`.

Comment: how can I come to know that what is your requirement ?

Comment: I give you the way to pass the value from jsp to servlet if you want some thing else then please specify that

Comment: Can't I call this input outside the form

Comment: Yes you can, but then you need to do this using JS

Comment: sorry @mahi but I don't get your requirement so please specify it first,
because retrieval in JS is not accessible in servlet it can be use only in jsp page because JS execute as client browser.